# How to format-on-save HTML-Eex files in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: html, elixir, phoenix-framework, visual-studio-code

I use Visual Studio Code editor for almost everything and also during my journey to learn Elixir and Phoenix. One thing that drives me crazy, I can't find a way to format the HTML-EEx template files. I am looking for a pleasant experience like with Prettier in JavaScript context, ElixirLS extension for Elixir itself or the Python extension.

What settings do you use to format HTML-EEx files in Visual Studio Code? Which extension do you use?

Comment: Is this can help? https://elixirforum.com/t/visual-studio-code-html-eex-support/12712/4

Comment: @MoshFeu Thanks for the link. Sadly, this didn't solve my issue. But it is a good pointer to start my own research.

Comment: Good luck with the research :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use beautify. And You have to add in your settings files:     `"beautify.language": { "html": ["htm","html","html-eex"]}`
Cautious the lower-case of "html-eex".

Comment: Thanks a lot. That looks good except a single missing indention.